# printing bitmap next to text in android

Tags: android, android-studio, printing

i need your help for my problem. I need to print a bitmap and next to it a text. When i try to print it , the printer prind my bitmap and then change line and print my String.Can you pls tell me how to make printer do not go to the next line?? i have look at the sdk's printer but there is no command like this.So pls tell me what i need to do. Thanks.
My printing template

```
line 1-5 Bitmap 
line 6 the String
```

and i want

```
line1-5 Bitmap      string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i fixed my problem was i created a Canvas with a bitmap on it. I put the logo to the x and y i want at Canvas and the text too. Then i took the bitmap and print it.

so i print logo and text

```
line 1-5 Bitmap      string
```